# Windows 7.5 phones! and other mobile devices, how to make the text stay the same size?

Tags: html, css

This has been doing my head in for a good part of half a year..

Has anyone found a way of making text stay the same in windows 7.5 and other mobile devices for a html email? 
I have in the passed used -webkit-text-size-adjust none/100%; with no luck and some other methods

Has anyone else got any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: need specific example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a meta tag in your head tag to prevent device zooming

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Legend sir, you are a legend. One day I will be able to pass this on to someone else as foolish as myself.